Localization Issue when executable name changes
I have a WPF application with name install.exe and the primary namespace is InstallNameSpace
I have added resource files (.resx) for English, Chinese and Japanese languages. When the project is build, it creates the following structure:

Basically the bin folder contains Install.exe and three sub folders named after 3 languages and the resource dll in them.
I launch my application and everything works fine. On change of language, the UI is updated with strings from that language.
I have another mode where I change my executable name. I just copy the built Install.exe and rename it to Uninstall.exe
When I launch the Uninstall.exe, it does not show localized strings and always shows strings in Default language which is English.
I renamed all three resource dlls in my sub folders to Uninstall.resources.dll so that it matches with my application. Still it does not show the strings in localized OS.
What am I missing? Is it possible to achieve this? How can I rename the executable and dlls after they are built and still have it launch localized?
Edit: I was able to solve it by keeping the resource dll(s) name unchanged. They still are named as Install.resources.dll
Apparently, the name of the executable does not matter. Internally it is Install.exe so it keeps looking for the resources with names Install.resources.dll

I don't think you can just rename the files as the compiled-in identity would be the original Install.* names for assembly-binding purposes. If you want to share code but have differently named entry-points you'll probably need to compile two separate EXE projects with different names that reference a shared common DLL containing the localisation. Alternatively, just create a shortcut file called "Uninstall" that just points to the Install program.

Just tried it and just not renaming the Satellite Assemblies should actually work. Some specifics about that program that is more then "i just compiled it"? Like is code signing/strong naming or something like that involved?

@Ralf Information on signing/strong naming etc. does not have any impact on localization and therefore those were not mentioned.

@TheKing Not for localization itself but for finding the satellite assembly with the localization in it. As i said for me it simply worked and so i'm trying to find the difference in your setup.

@Ralf Thanks for clarifying. I could make it work. Have edited my question with the solution.

I always keep my resx files in a dedicated class library project, which the remaining projects reference. I do this for tidiness more than anything, but it should help in your scenario as the references won't break if you rename the main (startup) project's exe.
